# If Statement with css and viewport

Tags: css, if-statement

I wanna to get an if-Statement in CSS.
If the viewport is under 1000px, then css should do sth. and then also an else-Statement.
Is it possible only with css, or does I also need Java or sth. else

Comment: You're looking for [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to do so:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 999px) {
  /* Place your styles here  */
}

@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  /* Place your other styles here  */
}
```